# 2GP: How to Upgrade Beta Managed Packages

Tags: managed-package, second-generation-packaging

Is there any way, or is there any plan (safe harbour) to make it possible to upgrade a `Beta` managed package without needing to uninstall the previous version first?

Comment: don't think there is anything as such as of now. There is an idea here. Consider upvoting it https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000XfLfAAK

Comment: @MohithShrivastava thanks for the link. I would say, however, that my experience of the trailblazer ideas zone is that ISV-related ideas languish (this example is 9 years old) because they typically address technical aspects that receive few upvotes since they are (perceived as) irrelevant to the wider Salesforce community.

Comment: @PhilW I agree here. ISV features need some love. The other way I can think of is working with your ISV Technical Evangelist to see if they communicate this along to the Product teams. I checked our internal systems here and this idea has been communicated for sure by various customers. I will see how I can channel this internally here.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - Thank you for all your help over the last few days